# How to create a View - SQL

Tags: sql, create-view

Create a view named `nc_num_pos` which shows all `nc_jobs` information along with the total number of pos for each row of nc_jobs.

Remember to specify all the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause that are in the `SELECT`, but are not in an aggregate function.

---

Test:

```
SELECT *
FROM nc_num_pos;
```

Expecting:

```
job_id      cust_id     job_date    descr       jobtype     num_pos
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
002         E05         1990-03-03  BUS REPORT  N           2
```

Got:

```
***Runtime error***
Program does not use the nc_jobs view or is badly laid out.
```

From using:

```
CREATE VIEW nc_num_jobs AS 
SELECT b.job_id, b.cust_id, b.job_date, b.descr, b.jobtype,  COUNT(po.job_id) as num_pos
FROM Bookjobs b, Publishers p
WHERE b.cust_id = b.cust_id
GROUP BY b.job_id
HAVING p.creditcode = 'C'
AND b.jobtype = 'N';
```

With, schema being:

[View schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3jPh.png).

---

Cannot seem to get what is expected. Unknown DBMS used. Behaves like PostgreSQL and not mysql.

Comment: First of all: tag the specific sql language you're using.

Comment: Unknown DBMS used. Behaves like PostgreSQL and not mysql.

Comment: 2. Please try to be more specific. "I cannot seem to get it right." doesn't mean anything to us. 3. It's O.k to ask questions about your homework here, but it should be focused questions about specific problems, we will not write your code for you, nor will we do your homework for you. 4. You ignored the part of the assignment that says "Remember to specify all the columns in the GROUP BY clause that are in the SELECT, but are not in an aggregate function". This is the reason why you can't create the view.

Comment: Take one step at the time. Start with a JOIN. Add WHERE. Add GROUP BY. When the result is fine, CREATE VIEW.

Comment: How on earth do you not know which database you're using?  That's a horrible way to live life :(

Comment: Your test says `nc_num_pos`, your `CREATE VIEW` says `nc_num_jobs`, and your error says `nc_jobs`.  There are many ambiguities here.  Are you sure the test, error and view are all from the same test run?

Comment: AFAIK, `postgreSQL` won't allow `SELECT a, b, c FROM x GROUP BY a`, it will insist that you `GROUP BY a, b, c`?  Although you say it's not `MySQL`, that ***is*** one DBMS that would allow you to do that...

Comment: Thank you. I changed nc_num_pos to nc_num_jobs, and I still get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Your view doesn't make sense.  I am guessing that you intend:

```
CREATE VIEW nc_num_jobs AS 
    SELECT b.job_id, b.cust_id, b.job_date, b.descr, b.jobtype,  
           COUNT(po.job_id) as num_pos
    FROM Bookjobs b JOIN
         Publishers p
         ON b.cust_id = b.cust_id
    WHERE p.creditcode = 'C' AND b.jobtype = 'N'
    GROUP BY b.job_id, b.cust_id, b.job_date, b.descr, b.jobtype;
```

Notes:

- The `HAVING` conditions used no aggregation functions, so I assume they are intended as `WHERE` conditions.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.
- I included all the unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.  This is a good practice if you are learning SQL.